# How to set template from file in module's directory?

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom template for address book editing form somewhere in Magento's `design` directory:

```
<layout>
<customer_address_form>
 <reference name='customer_address_edit'>
   <action method='setTemplate'><template>customer/address/edit.phtml</template></action>       
 </reference>
</customer_address_form>
</layout>
```

However, it isn't very convenient keeping that template there - I'd prefer to have `edit.phtml` in my module's directory. How can I point to template which is in my module's directory path? What should I put instead of `???` ?

```
<action method='setTemplate'><template>???/app/code/local/ContactologyProduct/LogProductUpdate/layout/edit.phtml</template></action>
```

Breadcrumbs ("`../`") work for pointing to external CSS and JS files, but it doesn't seem to work for templates.

Answer (score 0):

For example: Your module name is **vanfolmert**, in your `layout.xml` use below code

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <vanfolmert_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="vanfolmert/vanfolmert" name="vanfolmert.edit" template="vanfolmert/edit.phtml"/> 
        </reference>
   </vanfolmert_index_index>
</layout>
```

Your template structure should be like

```
template/vanfolmert/edit.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, we can see that Magento Logics distinguished into 3 logic sections.

**M** - `model` :- database communication of application carried by this directory

**V** - `View` :- Your fontend views are defined in this directory

**C** - `Controller` :- As the name states, it controls your application. It takes data from Model and provide to view.

Note : Magento cant categorize into only to these three sections. When we come deep into it, we can recognize some other logic divisions. But generally we can say that it has an MVC structure.

*Why Magento and several other frameworks holds MVC structure ?*

The answer to this question is very important. Since the business logic is divided into three sections, It is easy to configure and manipulate. For example if you need to change the heading of a page. If you are aware of MVC model, you will understand at least that, you need to edit a view file and do not want to look in controller and a model file. Thus MVC structure makes all things easy for you.

Keeping that in mind. Let us analyse your problem. In your `layout` file, it sets a template and it looks like this

```
 <action method='setTemplate'><template>customer/address/edit.phtml</template></action>
```

This means, whenever magento needs to render your address form, it looks for this template file. Where will it look ? Yes. You are absoultely guessing right. In `View` Directory. Where is your view directory? Hm... its tricky. But once you go around it, you can find that Magento's view section again distributed into 2 sections. They are

`app/design/frontend | adminhtml` - Normally holds layouts and templates

`skin/frontend | adminhtml`- This directory holds css js etc.

So magento will search for your file in this location

`app/design/frontend|adminhtml/<package>/<theme>/template/customer/address/edit.phtml`

where

`adminhtml` :- holds all templates that constitute your admin side of magento

`frontend` :- that holds template files of front view of magento.

I have explained all these in detail because, when you are creating a module, **you should always keep your template files in 
*app/design/adminhtmlfrontend/<.your_package>/<.your_theme>/template*.**

What you need to achieve here is to set your template file. Say, you need to keep your templates in `ContactologyProduct/LogProductUpdate/` directory, then you need to create those directories inside

`app/design/ntend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/contactlogyproduct/logproductupdate/edit.phtml`

and set your template as

```
 <action method='setTemplate'><template>contactlogyproduct/logproductupdate/edit.phtml</template></action>
```

When you create very complex modules, you may have multiple view files (template files). Since you are going to save those templates `contactlogyproduct/logproductupdate` directory, in future, when you need to look your template files, it will become more easy for you. That is because you know where you need to look for your template files.

Note: When you put something insdie `<template/ >`, magento expect those file inside `app/desing/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template`.

Comment: I see your point, but fanatic sticking to MVC is pointless to me in this case - keeping all module's files in one place makes more sense, that way module becomes more portable. Besides, Magento directory system is such a mess that I see no point in obeying it at all.

Comment: @van_folmert : Yes I know. First time it feel as messy one. But Once you have used with magento's file structure, it will be easy for you to obey `magento ways`. As I pointed out in last, magento looks for your file in `app/desing/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template`. Whatever be the path you specified inside `<template />`, magento appends that path to the above directory. So what you are trying to achieve is pointless

Comment: I think it's wrong because such approach where modules can't include layout files leads to situations where users have to **manually** (!) edit layout files to make module work. Example of module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-field-in-checkout.html, that doesn't work without layout editing (http://magentojack.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/add-custom-field-in-checkout/)